# The uiactionsheet crash

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiactionsheet

I have an action sheet which works like this:

```
- (void)Method1 {
    UIActionSheet *photoSourceSheet=[[UIActionSheet alloc]
                                     initWithTitle:@"Options"
                                     delegate:self
                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"Exit"
                                     destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                     otherButtonTitles:@"opt1",@"opt2", @"opt3", nil];
    photoSourceSheet.tag=1;
    photoSourceSheet.delegate=self;
    [photoSourceSheet showInView:self.view];
}

- (void)Method2 {
    UIActionSheet *photoSourceSheet1=[[UIActionSheet alloc]
                                      initWithTitle:@"Select Video"
                                      delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                      destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"Take New Video", @"Choose Existing Video", nil];
    //   photoSourceSheet.delegate=self;
    photoSourceSheet1.tag=2;
    photoSourceSheet1.delegate=self;
    [photoSourceSheet1 showInView:self.view];
}
```

then in my delegate i have:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex: NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (actionSheet.tag==1) {
        if (buttonindex==2) {
            [self method2];
        }
    } else if (actionSheet.tag==2) {
        // some code
    }
}
```

My delegate method gets called for the first action sheet i.e. photoSourceSheet but not for photoSourceSheet1.
Is there something special I need to do, like manually dismissing the sheet?
My second `UIActionSheet` (photoSourceSheet1) appears but it crashes the app as soon as I select an option on the sheet. 
It throws EXEC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: Show us your `// some code` because it looks like it crashes there =)

Comment: Like I said it never goes to "some code" as the delegate method doesnot get called..

Comment: How do you know that? Breakpoints?

Comment: Have you tried manually dismissing the sheet?  (I didn't check to see if it would work, but you suggested it and it seems reasonable.)

Comment: I just realised..Since I am using the delegte method didDismissWithButtonIndex so the first sheet is bound to close before calling the method2? right?

Comment: Since I have wasted whole lotta time on this so I was just playing around. When I put the same method2 code in the delegate method itself it worked. The exact same method...I am still flabergasted but I am not sure what goes wrong when I put it in a method. So I ll stick to this solution for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the above code.
EXEC_BAD_ACCESS is basically due to ill Memory Management.Sometimes you unintentionally remove the object that is being used.
Try enable Zombies it will tell you the exact problem area.

Steps: Go to Edit Scheme
       Memory Management
       Check the option **enable Zombie Objects**